# Print log in unix starting text

Tags: linux, unix, logging, grep

I have a huge log file and I wanted to copy a log starting from text to my local directory.

log file name

```
'cktrm.ecg-2015-12-21.gz'
```

command I ran was

```
bash-3.2$ gzgrep '2665941' cktrm.ecg-2015-12-21.gz > ~/log.txt
```

but this only copy all the lines that contains 2665941 to the text file.

What I need is to copy starting from that text to the end of the file.

For example:

```
...
log.info [id = 2665941]
log.debug ....
log.debug ...
log.debug [add to id 2665941]
...
```

what currently printed to text file is

```
log.info [id = 2665941]
log.debug [add to id 2665941]
```

what I need is

```
log.info [id = 2665941]
log.debug ....
log.debug ...
log.debug [add to id 2665941]
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a short awk program that prints its input starting from where it finds a pattern:

```sh
zcat cktrm.ecg-2015-12-21.gz | awk "/2665941/ {printLog = 1}
printLog { print }" > ~/log.txt
```

Note: this is a *single command*, but it consists of two lines. If you press enter while in the middle of a quoted string bash will give you a secondary prompt and you'll be able to continue to the next line of the command, where of course you'll need to close the quote.

The `zcat` uncompresses your file and its output is the input of the awk command.

The awk script means:

1. When the current line matches the given pattern (in this case `2665941`), set the `printLog` parameter to 1.
2. When the printLog parameter is set to something nonzero, print the current line.

This means that from the moment it finds the first occurrence of the pattern, it will print all lines.

Finally, the output of `awk` is redirected to your requested file.

Comment: sorry but i cannot use zcat, zgrep etc. it is on the admin network and i dont have permission to use external program either.

Comment: @user3659052 But you used gzgrep... And what external program are you talking about?

Comment: actually this works. just had to change zcat to gzcat

Comment: I was dumb, rushed and didn't thought of after porting entire file i could use the vim to do the search and trim files.

Comment: @user3659052 Actually, using `vim` for very large files is going to be problematic. It creates a lot of data on disk to help recovery and undo operations.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the specific format of the start and end markers you can use awk to achieve what you need:

```
cat > test-file
hear no evil
no evil here
start see no evil
know no evil
no evil known here
end see no evil
no know evil
^D
```

To only display lines between 'start see no evil' and 'end see no evil'

```
cat test-file | awk  -e '/start/,/end/ {print}'
```

results in the following output

```
start see no evil
know no evil
no evil known here
end see no evil
```

Comment: this i knew, but the problem is when there are more lines that can fit in your screen and you wont able to export to check the logs later in a text file when admin clear the cache box